# Boot up in Free form mode for android O

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo, multi-window, freeform

I am working on Android O source code and I have a requirement to use the free form mode. Right now, if we want to go into free form mode then we need user's intervention. I want to avoid that step and directly go to free form mode. How can I achieve free form mode after boot up of my machine.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

you must do the following

adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support 1

And I think go into developer options and set "force activities to be resizable"

Then you go clear all activities.. (you must do this)

Now launch an app and then bring up the list of apps again.. You will see the single app.  In the upper left corner next to the close x you will see what looks like a box overlapping a box.  Touch that and the app will convert to being freeform.

More info found here

[Android Nougat Freeform--but works for Oreo too!](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-nougats-freeform-window-mode-what-it-is-and-how-developers-can-utilize-it/)

Comment: This can be used in phones but if you are working on Car version of Android like Ncar or Ocar, then you will not be able to do it in this way. Moreover I asked for no user intervention.

Comment: Oops. Sorry missed the no-user-interaction stuff...  I guess if the user can do this (like once) though not user-friendly.. yes.  I'm not sure where you are going with car-version as only car-stuff is Android Auto and that itself is a totally different beast methinks.  (or do you mean Nougat-car and Oreo-Car as in Android Automotive? Which isnt around for user to actually do anything with (yet). and if yes then well if your building that then you could turn it on inside that platform

Comment: Yes, I tried enabling it in platform but till now no luck. :(